# Remove Extra space at the end of xltabular section

Tags: tabularx, xltabular

I have a section like this:

```
\section{Languages}
\vspace{-30pt}
\noindent\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{
        @{}>{\small}p{.15\textwidth}
        X@{}
}

& \textbf{Persian}: Native / Bilingual Proficiency \\[5pt]
& \textbf{English}: Full professional proficiency \\ [5pt]

\end{xltabular}
```

which gives the following output:
[image]

I want to change the vertical space between the last row of this section ("English...") and the (horizontal line) start of the next section ("Skills").

I didn't find any solutions for this. I tried `\vspace{-10pt}` and `parskip` but no luck. I am a beginner in LaTeX and don't understand its basics quite well.

The reason why I used `xltabular` instead of `tabularx` was because my sections span across pages. The format I defined for the table (`@{}>{\small}p{.15\textwidth}...` is not being used in this example, but I need it in general.

Comment: It's not easy to assess what's going on in a code snippet. Have you tried removing the surplus line-break instruction `\\ [5pt]`?

Comment: It also looks like you're massively abusing the `\section` syntax. Have you tried integrating "Languages" and "Skills" into the first column?

Comment: the -30pt back space is compensating for the mis-placed no-indent, you could remove both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're massively abusing the `\section` syntax. As a (presumably unwanted) side effect of your coding choice, you find it necessary to perform all kinds of horizontal and vertical spacing adjustments.

Rather than engage in such visual-formatting acrobatics, I'd like to suggest you employ a *single* `xltabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\midrule' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{% perform hanging indentation
   >{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash\hangafter=1\hangindent=1.5em}X}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\scshape}l L @{}}
\midrule
Languages 
& \textbf{Persian} Native\slash bilingual proficiency \\ 
& \textbf{English} Full professional proficiency \\ 
\addlinespace % optional
\midrule
Skills 
& \textbf{Programming languages} Python, Golang, Java, JavaScript, Kotlin (Android), C, Racket, SML \\
\addlinespace % optional
\midrule
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```